# bad options -t shell integration bash

Tags: shell, zsh, iterm2

$PATH/.iterm2_shell_integration.bash:type:257: bad option: -t . how to fix that error?  I use zsh.

i've tried to re-install zsh and commented it out the line 257 but it won't work.

code is built in from zsh

Answer (score 2):

The filename `.iterm2_shell_integration.bash` seems to indicate that this file is for `bash`.
Look in your `~/.zshrc` if you are sourcing this file, I suppose it shouldn't.

I think [you can download the correct file for zsh here](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html) (click on zsh) and source it as written on the site.

Comment: Yeah, you are right that I source this file because I can't run aliases that is written in bash_profile. Which is why i had to add to source this file in /.zshrc to run aliases.  What is another way to run aliases without sourcing the file?

Comment: Manually convert the `bash` script to `zsh` before sourcing it from zsh.